# Custom INPC type in WPF backed by dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to have this dynamic class

```
class FooViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private Dictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public void Set(string path, object value)
    {
        data[path]=value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(path);
    }

    public object Get(string path)
    {
        if(data.ContainsKey(path)){
            return data[path];
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged( String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

and if I set this as the DataContext to some WPF XAML I would like to be
able to databind to `two way bind` to keys in it.

```
<TextBox Text="{Bind Path=Foo}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Bind Path=Bar}"/>
```

and somewhere in my view model code I will have

```
var vm = new FooViewModel();
vm.Set("Foo", "Yeah!");
vm.Set("Bar", "Booh!");
```

What's the trick to do custom binding like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can derive your class from [DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) or implement [IDynamicMetaObjectProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.idynamicmetaobjectprovider.aspx). That should do the trick, as WPF supports binding to dynamic objects.

A good example of this is at http://www.shujaat.net/2012/09/dynamicobject-wpf-binding.html

```
class ViewModelBase : DynamicObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Private Members

    private Dictionary<string, object> _dynamicProperties;

    #endregion Private Members

    #region Constructor

    public ViewModelBase(IEnumerable<string> propertyNames)
    {
        if (propertyNames == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("propertyNames is empty");
        }

        _dynamicProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        propertyNames
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(propName => _dynamicProperties.Add(propName, null));
    }
    #endregion Constructor

    #region Public Methods

    public void SetPropertyValue(string propertyName, object value)
    {
        if (_dynamicProperties.ContainsKey(propertyName))
        {
            _dynamicProperties[propertyName] = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }

    public object GetPropertyValue(string propertyName)
    {
        return _dynamicProperties.ContainsKey(propertyName) ? _dynamicProperties[propertyName] : null;
    }

    #endregion Public Methods

    #region DynamicObject Overriden Members

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        bool ret = base.TryGetMember(binder, out result);

        if (ret == false)
        {
            result = GetPropertyValue(binder.Name);
            if (result != null)
            {
                ret = true;
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        bool ret = base.TrySetMember(binder, value);

        if (ret == false)
        {
            SetPropertyValue(binder.Name, value);
            ret = true;
        }

        return ret;
    }

    #endregion DynamicObject Overriden Members

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
}
```

Comment: *as WPF supports binding to dynamic objects* - Can you give us a source for this statement?

Comment: I'd like to see an example somewhere together with INPC support.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2009/11/02/new-wpf-feature-binding-to-dynamic-objects.aspx Not sure if that is offical source, but i tried it and it works.

Comment: Download sample in the linke above. INPC is implemented in the DynamicObjectClass

Comment: Interesting, not beautiful...but this should definitely work. :o)

Comment: Have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/174180/Dynamic-INPC-Clean-INPC and scroll down past the intro to ``Enter DynamicObject``

Comment: You could go also with System.ComponentModel.ICustomTypeDescriptor, but imo DynamicObject is cleaner and eaiser to implement.

Comment: @jure I added a found example to your answer. Thought I'd leave you with the credit as you pointed me in the right direction :)