# IL Emit - can you overwrite an existing assembly using reflection.emit?

Tags: c#, reflection.emit, mono.cecil

I understand that using reflection.emit is a run-time technique for generating types on-the-fly, contrast to compile-time techniques using PostSharp or Mono.Cecil, however, is it possible to overwrite an existing assembly using reflection.emit?

For instance, I have a TypeA in Types.dll assembly that I wish to emit the new type and save it (overwrite it) to the existing loaded Types.dll in my appdomain.

Would it be possible to overwrite the existing Types.dll in the appdomain using reflection.emit?

Comment: No. The code isn't necessarily even going to be used anyway - the code is compiled to machine code at some point, the memory layout is decided etc. If you need dynamic types, use dynamic types.

Comment: @Luaan thank you - I need to implement INPC for types shared between the client and the server (I prefer no attributes) and I'll take dynamic types into consideration. I might go with mono.cecil in this case. I have reflection.emit working for INPC + modification tracking, however, I might go with the mono.cecil approach - I'm not sure what the lesser of two evils is in this case - an error at runtime or an error at post-build-time. Performance isn't an issue since I'm caching the proxy generated from reflection.emit, however, I would be adding another assembly (loaded in memory).

Comment: I feel responsible to post this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273371/custom-inpc-type-in-wpf-backed-by-dictionary